# Add a countdown column to data.table containing rows until a special row encountered

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with ordered data labled up, and I want to add a column that tells me how many records until I get to a "special" record that resets the countdown.

For example:

```
DT = data.table(idx = c(1,3,3,4,6,7,7,8,9), 
                name = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b"))
setkey(DT, idx)
#manually add the answer
DT[, countdown := c(3,2,1,0,2,1,0,1,0)]
```

Gives

```
> DT
   idx name countdown
1:   1    a         3
2:   3    a         2
3:   3    a         1
4:   4    b         0
5:   6    a         2
6:   7    a         1
7:   7    b         0
8:   8    a         1
9:   9    b         0
```

See how the countdown column tells me how many rows until a row called "b". 
The question is how to create that column in code.

Note that the key is not evenly spaced and may contain duplicates (so is not very useful in solving the problem).  In general the non-b names could be different, but I could add a dummy column that is just True/False if the solution requires this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another idea:

```
## Create groups that end at each occurrence of "b"
DT[, cd:=0L]
DT[name=="b", cd:=1L]
DT[, cd:=rev(cumsum(rev(cd)))]
## Count down within them
DT[, cd:=max(.I) - .I, by=cd]
#    idx name cd
# 1:   1    a  3
# 2:   3    a  2
# 3:   3    a  1
# 4:   4    b  0
# 5:   6    a  2
# 6:   7    a  1
# 7:   7    b  0
# 8:   8    a  1
# 9:   9    b  0
```

Comment: +1. Was just reading the docs about `.I` and trying to think how it could be useful here, but am not familiar enough with `data.table` to figure out where to start!

Comment: They are all good answers, but I like this one best since it doesn't use any extra variables for carrying out the working.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure (or at least hopeful) that a purely "data.table" solution would be generated, but in the meantime, you could make use of `rle`. In this case, you're interested in reversing the countdown, so we'll use `rev` to reverse the "name" values before proceeding.

```
output <- sequence(rle(rev(DT$name))$lengths)
makezero <- cumsum(rle(rev(DT$name))$lengths)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
output[makezero] <- 0

DT[, countdown := rev(output)]
DT
#    idx name countdown
# 1:   1    a         3
# 2:   3    a         2
# 3:   3    a         1
# 4:   4    b         0
# 5:   6    a         2
# 6:   7    a         1
# 7:   7    b         0
# 8:   8    a         1
# 9:   9    b         0
```

Comment: Even if a pure `data.table` answer comes along, that is a definite +1 for lateral thinking.  And of course, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Corone -- One thing you didn't say is what you'd like to happen when (if ever) there are two "b"'s in a row. Ananda's and my answers differ in that case: mine assigns a '0' to both, while his begins the countdown for the next group following the first "b".

Comment: @JoshO'Brien good spot - the correct result is that b should always show zero.

Comment: @Corone -- Good. That's what I fig'rd.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a mix of Josh's and Ananda's solution, in that, I use RLE to generate the way Josh has given the answer:

```
t <- rle(DT$name)
t <- t$lengths[t$values == "a"]
DT[, cd := rep(t, t+1)]
DT[, cd:=max(.I) - .I, by=cd]
```

Even better: Taking use of the fact that there's only one `b` always (or assuming here), you could do this one better:

```
t <- rle(DT$name)
t <- t$lengths[t$values == "a"]
DT[, cd := rev(sequence(rev(t+1)))-1]
```

**Edit:** From OP's comment, it seems clear that there is more than 1 `b` possible and in such cases, all `b` should be 0. The first step in doing this is to create groups where `b` ends after each consecutive `a`'s.

```
DT <- data.table(idx=sample(10), name=c("a","a","a","b","b","a","a","b","a","b"))
t <- rle(DT$name)
val <- cumsum(t$lengths)[t$values == "b"]
DT[, grp := rep(seq(val), c(val[1], diff(val)))]
DT[, val := c(rev(seq_len(sum(name == "a"))), 
         rep(0, sum(name == "b"))), by = grp]

#     idx name grp val
#  1:   1    a   1   3
#  2:   7    a   1   2
#  3:   9    a   1   1
#  4:   4    b   1   0
#  5:   2    b   1   0
#  6:   8    a   2   2
#  7:   6    a   2   1
#  8:   3    b   2   0
#  9:  10    a   3   1
# 10:   5    b   3   0
```

Comment: +1 for another nice alternative! Just look out that someone doesn't come along and criticize your choice of `t` as an object name :)

Comment: Unfortunately our assumption about only 1 "b" (I thought so too) [is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231433/add-a-countdown-column-to-data-table-containing-rows-until-a-special-row-encount/15231752#comment21474827_15231752) :(

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a solution for all `b`'s to be replaced by 0.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, the last edit should do it, even though it is not the prettiest solution.